# query-params in <app-route> element of polymer

Tags: routes, polymer, query-string

I am using the `<app-route>` element in my application. I want to capture the queryParams in the URL

e.g.

> localhost:8080/#/test?foo=bar&baz=qux

The code I have written:

```
<app-location id="location" route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
<app-route id="route"
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
```

when I use the above URL
I get the

```
this.$.route.routeData.page = "test?foo=bar&baz=qux"
this.$.route.queryParams = {}
```

I was expecting

```
this.$.route.routeData.page = "test"
```

and

```
this.$.route.queryParams = {
   foo : "bar",
   baz : "qux"
}
```

I looked at the example in polymer documentation, but it did not help. What am I missing?
Am I expecting something wrong? How is queryParams supposed to work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get the answer you do is that the url is wrong.  The # part comes at the end.

Try url

> localhost:8080/?foo=bar&baz=qux#/test

The clue is in the page parameter where it appears that the query params have been added to the page parameter.  They haven't, but the browser just thinks they are part of the hash and passes them over in `window.location.hash`. `app-location` parsing of the hash part splits on '/' so thinks the whole thing is part of the :page pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to make this element accept normal URLs? i.e. params at the end. This format works but it's weird and not standard.

Comment: @ShreepadPatil That *is* a normal URL for hash paths. All text that follows the `#` in a URI is treated as a single *fragment identifier*, and the standard ([RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.1)) specifies that the fragment identifier is last. See http://superuser.com/a/498625/68227.

Answer (score 6):

Bind to [`<app-location>.queryParams`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route?active=app-location#property-queryParams) to get the query parameters:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" query-params="{{queryParams}}">
```

Note also that `<app-location>.route` has an internal property that contains the query parameters: `__queryParams`. Technically, you could use that with the caveat of it possibly being unusable in the next release. (i.e., `this.route.__queryParams === this.queryParams`).

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qaoBJJ?editors=1001&foo=1&bar=1)

Comment: `this.route` actually has both `__queryParams` and `queryParams` and the latter is updated when ever the former changes in an observer.  See my answer as to why it doesn't work

Comment: @akc42, While `this.route.__queryParams` is linked to `this.route.queryParams`, the latter is not readable, which is what the OP is attempting to do. See https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qaoBJJ?editors=1001&foo=1&bar=1

Comment: @tony19 I was surprised to find out that this format used by the the polymer app-location/app-route is actually a standard, because up until now I've never seen it in practice this way. I am digging in this one my self (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379395/polymer-app-route-query-string-format) as I am performing a migration from pagejs to app-route and backward compatibility is a concern in this case. How can I keep this compatibility with app-route and How come Angular and PageJs don't use this format for query strings in SPAs?