# Polymer app-route query string format

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I replaced PageJS routing in our application with `app-location` and `app-route`, and everything seems to be working except the query parameters. I noticed it can only read URLs like `host?param1=val1#/view`, not `host#view?param1=val1` how PageJS used to.

Upon further digging, I discovered that this is actually an [RFC standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1).  I find it odd that PageJS and Angular can use the nonstandard query string format.

Is there a way to use the `query-params` attribute of `app-route` to read the nonstandard query parameters for backward compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-standard form works in PageJS because PageJS manually parses the query string from the URL by [extracting the text that follows `?`](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/blob/500fff7/index.js#L390) and then [parsing that for any hashes that need to be separated out](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/blob/500fff7/index.js#L397-L401). Angular might do something similar. On the other hand, `<app-location>` (and `<iron-location>`) uses the platform's [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to fetch the query parameters.

If you need to stick with `<iron-location>`, you could add backward compatible support by monkey-patching [`<iron-location>._urlChanged()`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-location/blob/f7539da/iron-location.html#L209), which is responsible for parsing the URLs for `<app-location>`.

*Monkey-patched `<app-location>`:*

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-app',

  ready: function() {
    this._setupAppLocation();
  },

  _setupAppLocation: function() {
    // assumes <app-location id="location">
    const ironLocation = this.$.location.$$('iron-location');
    if (!ironLocation) return;

    ironLocation._urlChanged = function() {
      this._dontUpdateUrl = true;
      this.path = window.decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname);
      if (window.location.hash.includes('?')) {
        const parts = window.location.hash.split('?');
        this.hash = window.decodeURIComponent(parts[0].slice(1));
        this.query = parts[1];

        // Prepend other query parameters found in standard location
        if (window.location.search) {
          this.query = window.location.search.substring(1) + '&' + this.query;
        }
      } else {
        this.query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      }
      this._dontUpdateUrl = false;
      this._updateUrl();
    };
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could switch to a Polymer element that supports parsing query parameters in either form out of the box. I recommend [`<nebula-location>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/arsnebula/nebula-routing) (which uses [`QS`](https://github.com/nire0510/qs) as its query string parser).

*Example usage of `<nebula-location>`:*

```
<nebula-location data="{{locationData}}"></nebula-location>
<div>foo=[[locationData.queryParams.foo]]</div>
<a href="[[rootPath]]#view?foo=123">#view?foo=123</a>
<a href="[[rootPath]]?foo=123#view">?foo=123#view</a>
```